# Does the Uniform Cauchy Criterion work the other way around

Tags: real-analysis

There is a definition in my book for the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions:

> Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\Bbb{R}$. A sequence of functions $f_n:E \to \Bbb{R}$ is said to converge uniformly on $E$ to a function $f$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
> $$n \ge N \implies |f_n(x)−f(x)|<\varepsilon \quad \text{for all }x \in E.$$

Now, the definition for the Uniform Cauchy Criterion is essentially the same, except that it states:

... Then $f_n$ converges uniformly on $E$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that
$$n,m \ge N \implies |f_n(x)−f_m(x)|< \varepsilon \quad \text{for all }x \in E.$$

My question is, does the Uniform Cauchy Criterion work the other way around i.e. if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $n,m \ge N$ implies $|f_n(x)−f_m(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x \in E$, then does this imply uniform convergence?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I've taken the liberty of formatting your question in MathJax. Let me know if I've messed anything up. Please check out our [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to do this for yourself, plus you can press [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4423250/edit) to see how this particular question has been formatted, and even play around with it (you can see the changes in real time).

Comment: Thank you @TheoBendit it looks great! I will take a look at the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if the uniform Cauchy criterion implies uniform convergence. To show this, note that for each $x \in E$, $(f_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ which is complete. Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for each $x \in E$. Call this limit $f(x)$. Prove that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$.